# Re-running the program in the same run

Tags: java, algorithm

> Write a program that reads integers, finds the largest of them, and counts its occurrences. Assume that the input ends with number 0. Suppose that you entered 3 5 2 5 5 5 0; the program finds that the largest is 5 and the occurrence count for 5 is 4.
>
> Design the program such it allows the user to re-run the
> program with a different inputs in the same run.

```
public void findLargestInteger(){
         
             
       //create Scanner object
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          int x;
       
          
        do { 
       //prompt user input
          System.out.print("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:");
       
       //declare variables
          int n, countNeg = 0, countPos = 0;
          float sum = 0;
          
        
       //calculate how many positive and negative values, total, and average
          while ((n = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
             sum = sum + n;
           
             if (n > 0) {
                countPos++;
             } 
             else if (n < 0) {
                countNeg++;
             }
           
          }
          
         //display results 
          if (countPos + countNeg == 0) {
             System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
             System.exit(0);
          }
         
          System.out.println("The number of positives is " + countPos);
          System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + countNeg);
          System.out.println("The total is " + sum);
          System.out.println("The average is " + (sum / (countPos + countNeg)));
         
       }while ((x = input.nextInt()) != 0);
}
```

How can I get the prompt to display correctly at the end and keep it
running?

Output:

```
Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:
1 2 3 0 
The number of positives is 3 
The number of negatives is 0 
The total is 6.0
The average is 2.0 
1 
Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:
1 2 3 0 
The number of positives is 3 
The number of negatives is 0 
The total is 6.0 
The average is 2.0 
1 
Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:
2 3 4 0 
The number of positives is 3 
The number of negatives is 0
The total is 9.0 The average is 3.0 
1 
Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:
2 3 4 0 
The number of positives is 3 
The number of negatives is 0 
The total is 9.0 
The average is 3.0
```

Comment: Your code is awkwardly cut off, and still pretty long. I'd suggest reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) As well as [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So the last part of your question is what you want the output to look like or what it already looks like? (if you imagine a couple of line breaks ;))

Comment: The program needs to rerun automatically. However, it doesn't

Comment: the line breaks were removed by the site format. This is how it already looks except that it won't prompt correctly for the second run

Comment: What does that mean "it won't prompt" correctly? Does it tell the user to input numbers but then doesn't allow him to?

Comment: If that's the output you already get it kind of seems like it DOES rerun the method though...

Comment: your condition in do while says to stop once it encounters 0. you might want to add another while loop on the outside of your current dowhile loop. is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Why would he have to create another do while loop? It's already enough loops ^^ He just has to change the breaking condition.

Comment: Okay so am I right in assuming your problem is that the user has to input an additional number before the program restarts?

Comment: So, after printing The average is: , it doesn't print the first line in the do loop

Comment: Mark, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could change `while((x = input.nextInt()) != 0);` to `while(true);` if you really want to keep repeating your program. 
That IS an infinite loop though which is not really a good way to go.

So instead of looking for the next integer and compare with 0, maybe you should write something like

```
System.out.print("Do you want to quit? (y/n): ");
```

at the end of your loop (right before the `while((x = input.nextInt()) != 0)` line).

And then not check for 0 but for the `y`. At least then you don't have the program waiting for the user to input something without knowing what's happening.

Edit: Or you can just use a counter if you want to run it like twice or three times before it terminates ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just calling your function inside a while loop?

```
public void findLargestInteger() {
    // Your code
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        findLargestInteger();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue? (0/1) ");
        int n = reader.nextInt();
    } while(n == 1);
}
```